# awk : apply the same script on different files in parallel

Tags: awk, gawk

Apply the same set of commands parallelly on files provided

```
awk -which_option_goes_here? '{Run these commands in ll on files->}' files*
```

The manpage doesn't provide any information on this, but I think this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Use **GNU Parallel**:

```
parallel awk '1' ::: files*
```

Comment: I have thought of `parallel` but I wonder awk being here for so long, no awk specific options are available?

Comment: None that I know of - but let's wait and see :-)

Comment: No, there's no need to clutter up awk with non-text-manipulation functionality provided by other tools.

Comment: There you have it - if Ed says `awk` isn't cluttered with parallel, non-text processing stuff, then that's the way it is :-) Thank you, Ed.

Comment: If only someone had asked me about cluttering `grep` with `find`-like options to search for files. Grrrr ;-).